# TFS get Changeset number from Label

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I've created a Label on my Main Branch. I'd like to merge from this Label as source into a Target Branch.

It now seems I can't do this from a Label (Merge dialog only allows to choose Changeset in Source, not Label).

I tried to view the Label information but it's showing a different Changeset number for each folder. The topmost folder is showing the Changeset of when it was created, not the Latest Changeset from when it was Labelled).

The simple question is: How can I get the Changeset number from a Label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to merge from a Label. In the Merge Wizard select **"All changes up to a specific version"** and click **Next**

[image]

Then select **Label** for the **Version type**.

[image]

Then specify a **Label**

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I managed to miss that! Many thanks. I'm also wondering about the above dialog description saying "Specify the version up to which...". In my understanding it's up to **and** including.

Answer (score 2):

Labels let you take a snapshot of your files. Applying a label provides many of the same benefits as creating a branch, but typically with lower cost and complexity.

So, in other words, after you have applied the label, you can definitely use it to qualify operations such as building, **branching, merging**, comparing, and getting specific versions of files and folders.

You can merge a branch by Changeset/ Date/ Label / Lateset Version/ Workspace Version. More details from MSDN: [Merge folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428.aspx)

Moreover,if you click A**ll changes up to a specific version**, then the Select the versions of the source items page appears. And it will reduce the risk of conflicts in future merges.

**You are missing the option to merge label due to you had selected the `Selected changesets` option.**